# Powershell, command line and event logs

Tags: powershell, logging

We added the following to the powershell profile in an effort to collect what's typed in the command line.

```
$LogCommandHealthEvent = $true
$LogCommandLifeCycleEvent = $true
```

But how do I get the info from here, I'm looking for what's typed in the command line into the powershell console -

```
$event = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname=’Windows Powershell'; id=500} -MaxEvents 1
$Event.Message
```

gives me the info but all I want is the last line "CommandLine"

```
Details: 
    NewCommandState=Started

    SequenceNumber=313

    HostName=Windows PowerShell ISE Host
    HostVersion=4.0
    HostId=6fda55e7-4366-4719-ad59-8962eda1521f
    EngineVersion=4.0
    RunspaceId=e82c8130-1c67-4d61-b513-9ac55bc148ba
    PipelineId=52
    CommandName=Get-WinEvent
    CommandType=Cmdlet
    ScriptName=
    CommandPath=
    CommandLine=$event = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname=’Windows Powershell'; id=500} -MaxEvents 1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Message` property is one multi-line string, I would split it by newlines and select the last one:

```
$Event.Message -split "`r?`n" |Select-Object -Last 1
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias!  There may be a follow up question from me on adding the results of your answer to an array.  along with the event id and date.  But I'll take a crack at that one.